# Cannot reach/stop instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have GPU machine with local SSD attached, and I am unable to reach, stop or delete the instance. Currently the instance is shown as running in the console.

When I try to stop the instance, it says it cannot stop since there is a local SSD attached.

I cannot delete the instance because it has "deletion protection enabled", and I cannot disable deletion protection using the edit button on top of the console, since the instance is running.

I cannot reach the instance via the SSH button on console browser, or through another ssh client.

I resetted the instance using the console, but still the instance is unreachable.

Any ideas? It just keeps me billing :)

Comment: Do you have any important data on the local SSD? If not, couldn't you just try to detach it? I don't know exactly how local SSD works, so I can't say for sure whether my suggestion would work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was after I reset the instance, the local SSD could not be mounted correctly due to a problem with `fstab`. This prevented the bootup, and the SSH daemon couldn't start. In the end, I was able to use the serial console (if you click on the instance, in the page that opens there is SSH and serial for remote access, use the serial) and open up the command line. I shut down the instance from the command line (`sudo shutdown now`), then stopped and deleted the instance completely. No critical data was on the SSD.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that a mounted file system in the attached ssd disk is preventing the VM from shutting down.

You could try steps in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/detach-disk) to try to detach the disk:

1. Open a [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/quickstart)
2. Use the command:
   `gcloud compute instances detach-disk <your-vm-name> --disk=<ssd-disk-name> --zone <your-vm-zone>`

Once the ssd disk is detached from the VM you can try to stop it.

---